The image cannot be displayed because it contains error minio
I am currently developing the back-end of an application in nestJS and I would like to store images. I used minIO on docker, but when I want to retrieve the image from this url: localhost:9002/bucket-name/image-name.jpeg, I am told that the image cannot be shown because they contain errors. I've looked at a lot of posts from people who have the same problem but I don't understand. My bucket is in public. Here are the codes concerned:


version: '3.8'

services:
  minio:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/minio:2022
    environment:
      MINIO_ROOT_USER: 1234
      MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123456
    ports:
      - '9010:9000' 
      - '9002:9001'  
    volumes:
      - 'minio_data:/data'

volumes:
  minio_data:
    driver: local





@Injectable()
export class MinioService {
  private minioClient: Minio.Client;
  private bucketName: string;

  constructor(private readonly configService: ConfigService) {
    this.minioClient = new Minio.Client({
      endPoint: this.configService.get('MINIO_ENDPOINT'),
      port: Number(this.configService.get('MINIO_PORT')),
      useSSL: this.configService.get('MINIO_USE_SSL') === 'true',
      accessKey: this.configService.get('MINIO_ACCESS_KEY'),
      secretKey: this.configService.get('MINIO_SECRET_KEY'),
    });
    this.bucketName = this.configService.get('MINIO_BUCKET_NAME');
  }

  async createBucketIfNotExists() {
    const bucketExists = await this.minioClient.bucketExists(this.bucketName);
    if (!bucketExists) {
      await this.minioClient.makeBucket(this.bucketName, 'eu-west-1');
    }
  }

  async uploadFile(file: Express.Multer.File) {
    const fileName = `${Date.now()}-${file.originalname}`;
    await this.minioClient.putObject(
      this.bucketName,
      fileName,
      file.buffer,
      file.size,
    );
    return fileName;
  }

  async getFileUrl(fileName: string) {
    return await this.minioClient.presignedUrl(
      'GET',
      this.bucketName,
      fileName,
    );
  }



Thank you in advance
